# Python database connection not showing results

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodbc

I'm using this simple script, however, the for loop never executes. The script is terminated without any error - but the data is in the database. 2 weeks ago this script worked fine.
Does anyone know where the problem may be?
Thank you.

[image]

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=S:\Chat_OV_UL\O2Spokojenost\DtbO2Spokojenost.accdb;', autocommit=True)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from t_prepair')
print ("Databáze načtena")

limita = 0

for row in cursor.fetchall(): 
    limita = limita + 1 
    print(row[0])
    print(limita)
    print("----")
```

Comment: There is nothing in the datatable that is being fetched - add a print statement behind / outside the loop  as well - your data table is empty.

Comment: Can you share an image of what's in the t_repair table? or if it's sensible data, some hint of what it should be returning?

Comment: Yes, this is a screen from table. Table has 9000 rows. https://ibb.co/Z8NLcDD

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. Your code works fine for me on a table with 1_000_000 rows and 5 columns. You might try opening the database in MSACCESS.EXE and doing a Compact and Repair Database operation on it.